# Functions that only return variables in C

Tags: c

I want to call a function that will initialize an array and an integer variable and send them back from the function to the main program. I want to do that without even declaring those variables in the main program, but if I have to, then without initializing them in the main program. Is that even possible?

Comment: Depends if you're comfortable with the array being on the heap or the stack.

Comment: You will have to at least declare pointers in your main program, for the function to return values for.

Answer (score 2):

My C is rusty (haven't written any in ~17 years), but you'd probably do it with a `struct` (or a `typedef`'d `struct`) that the function returns:

```
struct foo {
   int   i;
   int * a;
};

struct foo * myFunction() {
    struct foo * pf;
    pf = malloc(sizeof(*pf));
    pf->i = 0;                            // Or whatever value it should have
    pf->a = malloc(100 * sizeof(*pf->a)); // Or whatever size it should have
    // ...fill in pf->a here...

    return pf;
}
```

...or something like that. Usage:

```
struct foo * pf = myFunction();
```

You'd probably want a function to release it, too, e.g.:

```
struct foo * releaseFoo(struct foo * pf) {
    if (pf != NULL) {
        if (pf->a != NULL) {
            free(pf->a);
            pf->a = NULL;
        }
        free(pf);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Usage:

```
pf = releaseFoo(pf);
```

(You don't need the return type and such, but it's really handy to have it so you can assign to the pointer you're freeing, so you don't have dangling pointers to freed memory.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not clear about a few things - can't myFunction be void? What does it mean when you write "struct foo *" before? And did you have to write the `*` in the line "struct foo * pf"?

Comment: @Eran: It can't be void if you want it to return something. It *could* be rewritten to accept an argument, say `struct foo **ppf` which it would then fill in (you'd then call it via `struct foo * pf; myFunction(&pf);`, but I don't see that buys you anything. The second question didn't come through (use backticks around things that may have angle brackets).

Comment: @Eran: It hadn't been before I commented above. Yes, you need the `*` (and the `malloc`), because otherwise the struct will be allocated on the stack, and when the function returns, that stack space is reclaimed and you can't use the pointer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example for your requirement.

```
void func(int *a)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       a[i] = i;
   return;
}

int main()
{

   int a[10],i;
   func(a);
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       printf("%d",a[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

Or

```
int *func()
{
   int i;
   int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) *10);
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       p[i] = i;
   return p;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *a = func();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"...I want to call a function that will initialize an array **and** an integer variable..."* Hence my using a struct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I have given two variants of how this can be done. On stack and heap. Similarly intger can also be initialized

Comment: @Gopi thank you. Just a quesion: Can I use the same function to return the integer as well? I did not understand your answer to T.J.

Comment: @Eran: That's because his answer to me didn't address the issue I raised.